# Codeigniter join two tables on date field

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to join two tables and get sum from each table for chart view (total_sell and hours_worked) needs to be group by week from date fields .

Table 1 -> daily_report
•daily_report_id
•date
•total_sell

Table 2 -> emp_payroll_hrs
•emp_payroll_hrs_id
•date
•hours_worked

my issue is with MySQL query below, please help.

```
$this->db->select('dr.*,eph.week_start,eph.hours_worked');
$this->db->from('daily_report dr');
$this->db->join('emp_payroll_hrs eph', 'WEEK(dr.date) = WEEK(eph.week_start)', 'left');
$this->db->select('WEEK(dr.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as drweek');
$this->db->select('SUM(dr.total_sell) as total_sell', FALSE);
$this->db->select('SUM(eph.hours_worked) AS hours_worked', FALSE);
$result=$this->db->get();
if($result->num_rows()>0)
{
    return $result->result_array();
}
else
{
    return array();
}
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting? You seem to have multiple `select` statements which is incorrect. The `join` looks good but the multiple `select` is likely the issue. What are you trying to achieve with those?

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT `dr`.*, `eph`.`week_start`, `eph`.`hours_worked`, WEEK(dr.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as drweek, MONTH(dr.date) as drmonth, YEAR(dr.date) as dryear, SUM(dr.total_sell) as total_sell FROM (`stoma_daily_report` dr) LEFT JOIN `stoma_emp_payroll_hrs` eph ON `WEEK`(`dr`.`date)` = WEEK(eph.week_start)

Comment: the issue is definitely on the multiple `select` statements, which is correctly being determined to be a syntax error. What exactly is it you are trying to achieve with those?

Comment: hi there thanks for your reply, I am trying to join two tables and get the sum of one column from each table for each week of the year. 
'total_sell' column from 'daily_report' table 
and 
'hours_worked' from 'emp_payroll_hrs' table

Comment: The fields you're "selecting" on the second, third and fourth `select` statements should go on the first `select` regardless of being fields that become available after the `join` statements. Try removing those select statements and adding the fields contained in those in the first `select`

Comment: you mean like below

$this->db->select('dr.*,eph.*,SUM(dr.total_sell) as total_sell,SUM(eph.hours_worked) AS hours_worked');
$this->db->from('daily_report dr');
$this->db->join('emp_payroll_hrs eph', 'WEEK(dr.date) = WEEK(eph.week_start)', 'left');
$this->db->select('WEEK(dr.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as drweek');
$result=$this->db->get();
if($result->num_rows()>0)
{
    return $result->result_array();
}
else
{
    return array();
}

Comment: No, yo need to get rid of all `select` statements but the first. Think "regular" SQL: `SELECT fields FROM first_table LEFT/INNER JOIN second_table on xxx=xxx LEFT/INNER JOIN third_table on yyy=yyy WHERE conditions GROUP BY field ORDER BY field ASC/DESC`... follow that same structure in query builder :)